# jupyter nbconvert --to html --no-inp is shrinking the display of centralized tables

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

Using the following code I am able to display nice side-by-side centralized tables in my jupyter notebook or in the converted HTML with code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from IPython.display import display, HTML
display(HTML("""
<style>
.output {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
}
</style>
"""))

df = pd.DataFrame(10000*np.ones((2,2)), columns = ['foo','bar'])
display(df)
display(df)
```

[image]

Nevertheless, if I convert `myfile.ipynb` to `myfile.html` without code using `jupyter nbconvert --to html --no-inp myfile.ipynb` the tables display with almost no horizontal space with long scroll bars, making them fairly unusable.

[image]

What can I do to keep the tables display as they are in the jupyter notebook?

Comment: I think you need to put "why are they shrinking like this and how to I unshrink them?" in the question body because there isn't an obvious question as written. And by shrunk do you mean zoomed in?

Comment: I have zoomed in because they are really small in the html. I have clarified the question. Thanks

Comment: I can't reproduce on my Mac, when I change the size of my window thin enough I get tables that look like that in both html and Jupyter but that isn't the same. may I know what browser and operating system you are using?

Comment: I am using ubuntu 20.04 + chrome

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly why the table thinks it needs to take up less space when there is so much available, by inspecting the html I can see lots of weird `prompt` and other empty containers... anyway...

the html styles that make the table get a scroll bar instead of just taking up full space is `overflow-x` in the `.output_subarea` element which is set to `auto` by something, which doesn't seem to be playing nicely with the other auto generated elements in a flex context.  so by setting it to `unset` I was able to show the full tables without scroll bars, not 100% sure this will do exactly what you want but seemed to fix similar issue for me.

```
display(HTML("""
<style>
.output {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
}
div.output_subarea {
    overflow-x: unset
}
"""))
```

It's quite possible this means that large tables will just take up all the space and never get a scroll bar, there is probably a better solution that could be found with more investigation but I'm not sure searching through css of Jupyter is the best way but I can't think of any other way. Hopefully this works for your case. :)

Comment: Cool! This works for my case since I am dealing with small tables! I am not marking the best answer because it will not work properly with large tables as you have pointed out.  I also think it is missing a comma between the dictionaries in the style command.

Comment: very reasonable, I'd also like to see a better answer be marked as accepted.  And I'm fairly certain commas aren't suppose to be put between dictionaries in css: https://i.stack.imgur.com/itYLd.png